# How can I add/remove the "checked" attribute via LWC controller data?

Tags: lightning-web-components, controller, html, checkbox

Brief context:
I have a page with n number of rows using `for:each={rows} for:item="row"`. Each row has its own checkbox.
There is a filtering feature that (by rerendering the  with a getter) hides/shows these rows from the DOM based on the entered criteria.

The issue is that the state of the checkbox is not "remembered" after being filtered out.

**Example:** Default for all checkboxes is unchecked > I check one checkbox ON > enter a criteria to filter out this checkbox from the page > remove the filter > my checkbox shows again and returns to default state, OFF.

Each row has the appropriate boolean via `row.isChecked` for whether or not it should be checked stored in my JS. Is there something analogous to the following?

HTML:
`<lightning-input type="toggle" checked={row.isChecked}></lightning-input>`

Because, unfortunately in HTML, the presence/absence of the 'checked' attribute controls the state.

I haven't found a way to effectively use the setAttribute() and removeAttribute() methods.

EDIT: I can NOT use querySelectors for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Boolean values, the attribute will behave as present when true, and not-present when false. There's no need to set/unset the attribute. Here's a working [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) example (copy-paste into a new component to test):

```
<template>
    <lightning-input label="Filter" onchange={filter}>
    </lightning-input>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr key={row.id} for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                <td>
                    <lightning-input label="Selected" variant="label-hidden" type="toggle" checked={row.checked} onchange={update} data-row-id={row.id}>
                    </lightning-input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {row.name}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    data = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Mickey Mouse', checked: false },
        { id: '2', name: 'Donald Duck', checked: false },
        { id: '3', name: 'Goofy Goof', checked: false },
        { id: '4', name: 'Pluto', checked: false }
    ];
    rows = [...this.data];
    filter(event) {
        if(event.target.value) {
            const p = new RegExp(event.target.value,'i');
            this.rows = [...this.data].filter(item => p.test(item.name));
        } else {
            this.rows = [...this.data];
        }
    }
    update(event) {
        this.data.find(item => item.id === event.target.dataset.rowId).checked = event.target.checked;
        this.rows.find(item => item.id === event.target.dataset.rowId).checked = event.target.checked;
        this.rows = [...this.rows];
    }
}
```

And here's a similar [webcomponents](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/VF4KChm4VX8MDj4IWCkM) demo you can play with.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you for this excellent example @sfdcfox. If I had 15+ rep I would upvote it.

Comment: @JMRiss If you want to, you can click the checkmark next to the answer. This will give me +15, you +2 points, as well as letting people know this answer solved your problem.